Angular: Align types among AbstractControls and classes
I tried but could not figure out how I could define and align types. For example,
export interface IDumpingFormSchema {
  requestNumber: string | null;
  employeeId: string | null;
  employeeName: string | null;
  department: string | null;
  companyCode: string | null;
  brand: string | null;
  lineItems: DumpingFormItem[] | null;
}

In my class, I can ensure the property implementations by implementing the IDumpingFormSchema:
export class DumpingFormData implements IDumpingFormSchema {}

However, in terms of FormControl, FormArray, and FormGroup, I wanted to ensure properties are defined and aligned. For now, I defined the type manually,
// should follow the schema's properties
export type IDumpingFormGroup = {
  requestNumber: FormControl<string | null>;
  employeeId: FormControl<string | null>;
  employeeName: FormControl<string | null>;
  department: FormControl<string | null>;
  companyCode: FormControl<string | null>;
  brand: FormControl<string | null>;
  lineItems: FormArray<FormControl<DumpingFormItem | null>>;
}

And in service, I can implement and ensure the return FormGroup align with the the IDumpingDroup.
  createDumpingApplicationFormGroup(): FormGroup<IDumpingFormGroup> {
    return this.fb.group({
      requestNumber: this.fb.control<string | null>(null),
      employeeId: this.fb.control<string | null>(null),
      employeeName: this.fb.control<string | null>(null),
      department: this.fb.control<string | null>(null),
      companyCode: this.fb.control<string | null>(null),
      brand: this.fb.control<string | null>(null),
      lineItems: this.fb.array([] as FormControl<DumpingFormItem | null>[]),
    });
  }

How can I dynamically use the IDumpingFormSchema and generate the IDumpingFormGroup type? Is there a way to do it such as DTO or DAO? Thanks.

You can create a couple utility types to help you dynamically derive your typed FormGroup.
First, we can use a Conditional Type to express a generic ControlType that will represent either a FormArray or FormControl depending on whether or not the type extends Array.
type ControlType<T> = T extends Array<infer U>
  ? FormArray<FormControl<U | null>>
  : FormControl<T>;

Then, we can use a Mapped Type to declare a generic FormGroupType that applies this type to all properties of your interface:
type FormGroupType<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: ControlType<T[K]>;
};

Now, you can use it like this to dynamically declare your form group type:
type IDumpingFormGroup = FormGroupType<IDumpingFormSchema>;


I tried this but the actual type isn't consistent.

What do you mean?

After doing this, the type will be requestNumber: FormControl<null> | FormControl<string>; instead of maual one: requestNumber: FormControl<string | null>;. Besides, I also got the same answer provided by AI.
